# Show that a function is invertible

Tags: calculus

I have to show that the function $f(x) = \frac{ax + b}{cx + d}$, where $ad - bc\neq 0$, has an inverse function.

I've tried some ways to go around it, i.e. checking if $g(f(x))$ has $x$ as an identity, but the algebra got really difficult and I could not get anywhere.

Any hints on how to solve this one?

Best,

Comment: How about you set
$$
\frac{ax + b}{cx + d} = y
$$
and try to solve for $x$ ?

Comment: If $g(x) $ is the inverse then $f(g(x)) =x\implies \frac{a g(x) +b} {cg(x) +d} =x$. Solve it for $g(x) $ and then check if $f(g(x)) =x$ and $g(f(x)) =x$

Comment: You can show this function as a matrix in the two dimensional projective space. Then the condition $ad-bc\neq  0$ just means that the determinant is non zero, i.e. the matrix has an inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically we have to prove that the function $f$ is bijective. We just need to show that

$\bullet~$ $f$ is one-one.

$\bullet~$ $f$ is surjective.

$\circ~$Now,
\begin{align*}
&f(t) = f(z)\\
\implies & \frac{at + b}{ct + d} = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}\\
\implies & actz + bcz + dat + bd = actz + adz + bct + bd\\
\implies & (bcz - bct) - (adz - adt) = 0\\
\implies & bc(z - t) - ad(z - t) = 0\\
\implies & (z - t)(bc - ad) = 0\\
\implies & z = t \quad [\text{as }~ ad - bc \neq 0]   
\end{align*}
hence $f$ is one-one.

$\circ~$ Let's consider an arbitrary $y$ $\in$ $\text{im}(f)$, such that
$$ y = \frac{ax + b}{cx + d} $$
Now we have that
\begin{align*}
&y = \frac{ax + b}{cx + d}\\
\implies & ycx + yd = ax + b\\
\implies & ycx - ax = b - yd \\
\implies & x (yc - a) = b - yd\\
\implies & x = \frac{b - yd}{yc - a}
\end{align*}
Therefore $f$ is surjective. Hence, the map is surjective + one-one = bijective, hence Invertible and the inverse exists. The co domain of $f$ is $~\mathbb{R}-\frac{a}{c}$ if $c \neq 0$, and if $c = 0$, then the map can be extended to $\mathbb{R}$.

Moreover the inverse function is
$$ f^{-1}(x) = \frac{b - xd}{xc - a} \quad \text{for } x \in \text{im}(f) $$

Comment: If $y=\frac{a}{c}$, then $x$ does not exist unless $\frac{a}{c} = \frac{b}{d}$. Thus if $c\neq 0$, then $f:R\to R-\{\frac{a}{c}\}$ has an inverse unless $\frac{a}{c} = \frac{b}{d}$. If $c=0$ or $\frac{a}{c} = \frac{b}{d}$, then $f:R \to R$ has an inverse.

Comment: The condition $\frac{a}{c} = \frac{b}{d}$ can be dropped as $ ad \neq bc$ given in question.

Comment: And that's why I didn't mention the co-domain. Just im$(f)$. :)

Comment: True. Now if $c\neq 0$, then $f:R\to R-\{\frac{a}{c}\}$ has an inverse. If $c=0$, then $f:R \to R$ has an inverse.

Comment: Yes restricting the co-domain to the im($f$), every 1-1 function has an inverse.

Answer (score 3):

The function is the Moebius function corresponding to the matrix $((a,b),(c,d))$. The inverse is the Moebius function corresponding to the inverse matrix.

Comment: Did you mean the Moebius function corresponding to the cofactor matrix ((b, -d), (c, -a))?

Comment: I meant the inverse matrix. But the function will be the same if you take the adjoint matrix as long as the determinant is not $0$.